# I can not install @tensorflow/tfjs-node using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to install @tensorflow/tfjs-node using

```js
npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node
```

But i git this erorr

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.7.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.7.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kit/.npm/_logs/2021-07-09T14_28_52_156Z-debug.log
```

And my node version: v14.11.0

Looking forward if someone have answer. thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: i use ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- npm cache clean --force
- delete node_modules folder
- delete package-lock.json file
- npm install

Comment: still the same problem for me.